# Removing first word from data frame cell when it starts with lowercase letter in R

Tags: r, regex, taxonomy

I want to clean up a taxonomy table with bacterial species in `R` and I want to delete values from all cells that start with the small letter.

I have a column from taxonomy df:

| Species |
| --- |
| Tuwongella immobilis |
| Woesebacteria |
| unidentified marine |
| bacterium Ellin506 |

And I want:

| Species |
| --- |
| Tuwongella immobilis |
| Woesebacteria |

```
unwanted <- "^[:upper:]+[:lower:]+"
tax.clean$Species <- str_replace_all(tax.clean$Species, unwanted, "")
```

but it doesn't seem to work and does not match desired species.

Comment: `^[:lower:].+` does it work?

Comment: It seems that it works! Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are working with dataframe, I suggest using `dplyr::filter` to clean up the dataframe.

`grepl()` returns logical values, `!grepl(^[[:lower:]])`  looks for anything that does not start with a lower case letter (`^` indicate the beginning of a string).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% filter(!grepl("^[[:lower:]]", Species))

               Species
1 Tuwongella immobilis
2        Woesebacteria
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
grep('^[A-Z]', df$Species, value = T)
[1] "Tuwongella immobilis" "Woesebacteria"
```